# Possibilty of DisplayPort over PCIe

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, gpu, displayport

I'm trying to figure out if it would be possible to add a DisplayPort to my Linux PC using a PCIe slot. I have found cards like http://www.ebay.com/itm/PCI-E-1x-Express-to-USB-3-1-Type-C-Dual-Port-Expansion-Card-Adapter-FE-/231787767332?hash=item35f7a0a624:g:ouoAAOSwHPlWc~4L that claim to offer USB-C ports through PCIe. Furthermore it seems that USB-C officially supports DisplayPort (http://www.displayport.org/what-is-displayport-over-usb-c/) and I have found devices like http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-3-1-Type-C-to-Mini-DisplayPort-DP-1080p-HDTV-Adapter-Cable-for-Macbook-/311479169477?hash=item48859af1c5:g:9g4AAOSwhcJWOs1z.

My concerns though are whether the Linux kernel has support for something like this because it would require copying the framebuffer over emulated USB-C. Does Linux even support this yet with proper CPU based USB-C?

Comment: A quick search on newegg turns up about 250 PCIe video cards with at least one DisplayPort adapter. Is there a reason you wouldn't want one of those?

Comment: I'd prefer not getting a whole nother gpu.